# Apple headphones on a Mac: make play/pause button work in Spotify

Tags: itunes, macbook-pro, headphones, spotify

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Headphone play/pause button controls iTunes only](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/52353/headphone-play-pause-button-controls-itunes-only)
>   [How can I make earphones with full inline controls work with VLC/Spotify?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/62835/how-can-i-make-earphones-with-full-inline-controls-work-with-vlc-spotify)

I have a retina MacBook Pro and I noticed that when I plug in the iPhone headphones and click the button on them, iTunes starts. However, I am using Spotify for music. Is there a way to reconfigure that button so that it works in Spotify?

Comment: [This question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/52353/headphone-play-pause-button-controls-itunes-only) may be the same underlying issue.

Comment: Other related questions: [1](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/62835/configuring-in-line-controls-for-earphones-on-os-x) [2](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/35916) [3](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/58234) [4](http://superuser.com/questions/31925/what-can-i-do-to-stop-the-play-pause-button-from-opening-itunes) [5](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/469/how-can-i-change-which-application-is-launched-when-i-press-the-play-button-on-m)

Comment: I voted to close this question as this is an exact duplicate of : [How can I make earphones with full inline controls work with VLC/Spotify?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/62835/13414)